Question regarding the fundamental group of a quotient space.
$\mathbf{The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $X:= S^2\times [-1,1]$ generated by $(x,t)\sim (-x,t)$ for $x\in S^2$ and $t\in \{-1,0,1\}.$ Show that $\pi_1(X/\sim,x_0)$(at any base point $x_0$) is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2\ast \Bbb{Z}_2\ast \Bbb{Z}_2$ and describe explicitly the loops $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ that generate $\pi_1(X/\sim,x_0)$(a pictorial description of $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ is enough, explicit formulas are not necessary).
$\mathbf{My \ Approach}:$ The space $S^2\times [-1,1]$ looks like concentric spheres $S^2$ with $t$ varying from $-1$ to $1.$ I thought of applying the Seifert- Van Kampen theorem but getting a bit confused about whether I am choosing the right neighbourhoods or not.Note,the relations are given by $(x,t)\sim (-x,t)$ for $x\in S^2$ and $t\in \{-1,0,1\},$ thus there are $3$ copies of $\Bbb{R}P^2$ corresponding to $t=-1,0$ and $1,$ and no identifications are going on in $S^2\times (-1,0)$ and $S^2\times (0,1).$ Now,I was choosing neighbourhoods $U,V$ and $W$ of $A:=[S^2\times \{1\}]\cong \Bbb{R}P^2,B:=[S^2\times \{0\}]\cong \Bbb{R}P^2$, and $C:=[S^2\times \{-1\}]\cong \Bbb{R}P^2$ respectively in such a way that $U,V,W$ retracts onto $A,B,C$ and $U\cap V,V\cap W$ retracts onto $[S^2\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}]\cong S^2, [S^2\times \{-\frac{1}{2}\}]\cong S^2$ respectively. Note, the intersections $U\cap V$ and $V\cap W$ are clearly path-connected but $U\cap W,U\cap V\cap W$ is empty. So, can we apply Van Kampen theorem here as we need to find the normal subgroup $N$ generated by all the elements of the form $i_{UV}(w)i_{VU}(w)^{-1}$ where $i_{ST}:\pi_1(S\cap T)\to \pi_1(S) ?$ Thanks in advance for some hints. If $N$ is the trivial subgroup, then the Van Kampen theorem says that $\pi_1(X/\sim,x_0)\equiv \pi_1(\Bbb{R}P^2)^{\ast 3}\equiv \Bbb{Z}_2^{\ast 3}.$

Who said that it is a free product of three cyclic groups of order 2?

@MoisheKohan, yes that's what I am a bit confused about whether I can apply Van Kampen or not.

You can but you are applying it incorrectly. The right answer is free group of rank 3.

@MoisheKohan, any hints about the right approach please ?
